# Eclipse debuging complex pointers datatypes. Show bad location

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, variables, pointers

I had something like this:

```
int *(*a)[2]; //pointer to array[2], which contains pointers to int.
a = (int *(*)[2]) malloc (4*sizeof(int *[2]));
int b=5;
(*a)[0]=&b;
(*a)[1]=&b;
```

funny is that this works ok, but when you use debuging mode and show variables you get answer for this:

```
a
    *a
        *a[0] <- but i want answear for (*a)[0]
            **a[0] <- but i want answear for *(*a)[0]
        *a[1]
            **a[1] <- but i want answear for *(*a)[1]
```

Eclipse show me different location. This make me angry. Its some future from eclipse? or bug?....
Because i thought before that i have some bad code, but all works fine. Only i cant check if values are on right place.

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: It is C++. Sorry, that i dont specific.